# Задачка про шахматную доску (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Поле шахматной доски определяется парой натуральных чисел, каждое из которых не превосходит 8. По введенным координатам двух полей `(k,l)` и `(m,n)` выясните, являются ли эти поля полями одного цвета?
>
> **Входные данные**
>
> `На вход программе подаются четыре целых числа k,l,m,n.`
>
> **Выходные данные**
>
> `Выведите YES или NO в зависимости от ответа на вопрос задачи.`

Ввожу вот такое решение:

```
k = int(input())
l = int(input())
m = int(input())
n = int(input())
if((k == l) and (m == n) and (k,l,m,n < 8)):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Пишет, что решение не верное.

Comment: посмотрите, как выглядит шахматная доска и какие там клетки одинакового цвета)

Comment: Вы считаете, что клетки одного цвета лежат всегда на главной диагонали?

Comment: Так как пофиксить то? Просто я и в условие задачи не особо вкурил.

Comment: Что конкретно вам непонятно в условии?

Comment: Про координаты двух полей. В смысле координаты?

Comment: `print('NO' if (k + l + m + n) % 2 else 'YES')`.

Comment: `print(('YES', 'NO')[sum(map(int, (input() for _ in range(4)))) % 2])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот самое понятное решение, как по мне

```
x1 = int(input())
y1 = int(input())
x2 = int(input())
y2 = int(input())
if (x1 + y1 + x2 + y2) % 2 == 0:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
k = int(input())
l = int(input())
m = int(input())
n = int(input()) # or k, l, m, n = (int(input()) for _ in range(4))

print("YES" if not ((k + l + m + n) % 2) else "NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input())
k=int(input())
b=int(input())
a=int(input())
v=(n+k)
d=(b+a)
if v%2==0 and d%2==0 or v%2!=0 and d%2!=0:
    print("YES")
else:
   v%2!=d%2
   print("NO")
```

Comment: Вот эта строка у вас ничего не делает фактически `v%2!=d%2`

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что координаты "черных" клеток будут в сумме четными, а "белых" - нечетными. Нужно проверить, является ли сумма попарных координат четными, и сравнить по этому признаку с другой парой координат. Проще всего проверить на четность (l+k+n+m). Если одна пара четная, а другая нет - значит мы получим нечетное число - клетки разного цвета. Если обе пары четные (или нечетные) - сумма будет четной, значит клетки, как минимум, одного цвета